# Word vs. Wordpad

Tags: microsoft-word

When I open a word file, now it is converted to a Wordpad file(?)  And then, when I save it, it is apparently saved in Wordpad format.  This new process just started when I had to recently re-install Windows 10 (and apparently a new version of Word) on my computer.  Why did Microsoft do this?  Is there some logic, some advantage, some improvement, that has made Word a better product?  Also, it is different enough from the previous version, that a significant learning curve is required to get back up to speed.  All in all, VERY IRRITATING.

Comment: *When I open a word file* No such definition like "word file". Specify its format or at least its extension.

Comment: Word (newest version) on Windows 10 does not save a document as Word Pad and does not even offer the option. Try uninstalling Office, restart and install it again

Comment: *now it is converted to a Wordpad file* What does this statement means precisely?

Comment: Open Word, open a document, then Save As, and in the drop down selection for file type, ensure you are saving as DOCX and not saving as RTF.  Saving as RTF may look like Word Pad.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have Word, run a repair. Here is how to do that: [Repair an Office Application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b).

When you replace Windows (not update, but reinstall) you would lose any Office programs. In that case, you need to [reinstall Office/Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/download-and-install-or-reinstall-office-365-or-office-2019-on-a-pc-or-mac-4414eaaf-0478-48be-9c42-23adc4716658).